Integral from $0$ to $2$ of a piecewise function: is this proof correct?
Let $f(x)=1$ on the interval $[0, 1)$ and equal to $-2$ on the interval $[1, 2]$. Prove that $\int_0^2f=-1$.
Let $P(f, \mu)$ be a sum over any given partition with norm $||P||$. Notice that the only area that changes depending on the partition is the area of the subinterval containing $x=1$. If in this interval we let $f(\mu_k)=-2$, then we will be subtracting a maximum of $3||P||$ from -1 (see the figure below). If in this interval we let $f(\mu_k)=1$, then we will be adding a maximum of $3||P||$ to -1. Thus, $-1-3||P|| \leq P(f, \mu) \leq -1+3||P||$, implying that $|P(f, \mu)+1|\leq 3||P||<\epsilon$. Let $\delta = \frac{\epsilon}{3}.$ 
Obviously a very rough proof, but I think this gets the idea across. I basically want to know whether it is valid to assume that we are adding or subtracting from -1, since I think this may rely on assuming that the integral is -1.

This is before proving that you can integrate like that.
